# Why does update in crypto-js output differ from NodeJS' crypto when updating IntArray

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm trying to refactor something that used NodeJS' `crypto` into something that uses `crypto-JS` but I'm running into some issue when I'm updating the hash content.

Here's the original hash that I wanted to replace:

```
const original_hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(someString).update(someIntArray).digest()
```

And here's the new hash using `crypto-js`:

```
const new_hash = CryptoJS.algo.SHA512.create().update(someString).update(someIntArray).finalize();
```

Does anyone know why the 2nd update is making such differences? An example of the `someIntArray` would be `Int8Array(6) [ 26, -50, -59, -118, -101, 33 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `CryptoJS.update()` does not support `Int8Array` as input, see [core.js#L561](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/971c31f0c931f913d22a76ed488d9216ac04e306/src/core.js#L561).

You can convert Int8Array to hex string, and parse it using `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse()`.

```
const int8ArrayToHex = (int8Array) => {
    // x << 24 >>> 24 converts int8 to uint8
    return Array.from(int8Array).map(x => (x << 24 >>> 24).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
}

let hex = int8ArrayToHex(new Int8Array([ 26, -50, -59, -118, -101, 33 ]))
console.log(hex) // 1acec58a9b21

const new_hash = CryptoJS.algo.SHA512.create().update(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hex)).finalize().toString()
console.log(new_hash) // 3c1d419bfcd4...
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d0kh57Ly/)

Result can be verified here: [CyberChef: From Decimal -> SHA512](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Decimal(%27Comma%27,true)SHA2(%27512%27)&input=MjYsIC01MCwgLTU5LCAtMTE4LCAtMTAxLCAzMw)

Comment: thank you! The CryptoJS doc surely didn't make it easy to find :P However, your suggestion worked beautifully, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! ;) I forget to mention that modern browser these days supports [WebCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest), and might provides better performance especially when processing large amounts of data.